# How do I get the ImageView contained inside a Pane?

Tags: java, image, javafx

### Situation

I have an application which contains a GridPane thats composed of multiple Panes. Inside of every Pane is an ImageView that allows me to display an Image inside that Pane. My application follows the MVC pattern and I would like my setPaneImage( ) function to dynamically change one Pane's ImageView image.

### Problem

I don't know how to access the Pane's ImageView ? I know you can use the ImageView's setImage( ) to change its image. To access the ImageView contained inside the Pane, I suppose you have to use the .getChildren( ) method but I can't figure out how I can implement this...

Here's the simplified code :

```
public class ViewController extends Application implements EventHandler
{
    final Image paneVide = new Image( "sample/img/paneVide.png" );

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception
    {
        // Initializing attributes
        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane( );
        gridPane = new GridPane( );

        Pane p = new Pane( );

        // Adding ImageView to the Pane
        ImageView imv = new ImageView( );
        imv.setPreserveRatio( true );
        imv.setFitHeight( p.getHeight() );
        imv.setFitWidth( p.getWidth() );
        p.getChildren().add( imv );

        // Setting handler
        p.setOnMouseEntered( this );

        // Adding to GridPane
        gridPane.add( p, i, j );

        // [...] Rest of the display code
    }


    @Override
    public void handle(Event event)
    {
        Pane p;

        if( event.getSource() instanceof Pane ) {
            p = (Pane) event.getSource();

            // MOUSE HOVER
            if( event.getEventType().toString() == "MOUSE_ENTERED" )
                setPaneImage( p, "VIDE" );
        }
    }


    // Here's the function where I don't really know what to do...
    // How do I access the Pane's ImageView so that I can dynamically
    // change its image ??
    public void setPaneImage( Pane p, String img )
    {
        switch( img )
        {
            case "VIDE":
                p.getChildren().add( new ImageView(paneVide) );  // Setting pane's image
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way would be to store a reference to the `ImageView` in a field:

```
private ImageView imv;

public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
    ...
    this.imv = new ImageView();
    ...
}

public void setPaneImage(Pane p, String img) {
    ...
    imv.setImage(paneVide);
    ...
}
```

Assuming the `ImageView` is the only child of the `Pane`, you could also retrieve the `ImageView` from the child list:

```
public void setPaneImage(Pane p, String img) {
    ImageView imv = (ImageView) p.getChildren().get(0);
    ...
}
```

---

**Additional notes:**

Some parts of your code could be considered bad practice:

```
if(event.getEventType().toString() == "MOUSE_ENTERED")
```

1. You're comparing `String`s using `==` instead of `equals`
2. Instead of comparing the type converted to `String` you should compare to the event type: `event.getEventType() == MouseEvent.MOUSE_ENTERED`
3. You don't need that check. It's the only event the handler listens to. Handling different types of events should be done using a different handler. You could create such a handler using anonymus classes or lambda expressions easily. You could avoid the source check using the same strategy.

```
public void setPaneImage(Pane p, String img) {
    switch( img )
    {
        case "VIDE":
```

Using magic strings is a bad idea. It's hard to find the error if you've got a typo in the string. You could simply just pass the `Image` itself (`paneVide`). This way you don't need the `switch` at all and any typos would become obvious on compilation.

```
imv.setFitHeight(p.getHeight());
imv.setFitWidth(p.getWidth());
```

You do this before the first layout pass. At that time the size of `p` is still 0. You should use bindings instead to accommodate for later updates of the properties:

```
imv.fitHeightProperty.bind(p.heightProperty());
imv.fitWidthProperty.bind(p.widthProperty());
imv.setManaged(false); // make sure p can shrink
```

It would also be beneficial to make sure the `GridPane` resizes `p`.

```
public class ViewController extends Application implements EventHandler
```

The `Application` class is the entry point to the program. Using it as controller and event handler violates the seperation of concerns principle. Also it's preferable to specify the type parameter for `EventHandler`.